# how to make proxied wordpress page not to change typed url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I am using apache rewriterule to redirect url when client SSL certificate is not used. When I am redirecting to static page using [P] proxy flag, everything work as expected. But if I change redirection to page in wordpress, typed url disapeared and there is wordpress page permalink. I want to leave unchanged typed url in address bar, just to be able to use reload after connecting to VPN or using correct certificate.

RewriteRules as used in virtual host conf.

```
  # SSL User Authentication
  SSLVerifyClient optional
  SSLVerifyDepth 3

  # redirect all url when not in VPN or LOCAL NET
  #RedirectMatch ^/(.*) http://terminus.terminus.cz

  # to be able to debug rewrite in apache2 error log
  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6

  # Error handling = unsuccessfull SSL user authetication
  RewriteEngine   on
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  # No authentification certificate
  RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trading\.terminus\.cz$ [NC]
  # RewriteCond {HTTP_REFERER} value is blank
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
  RewriteRule ^ http://terminus.terminus.cz/no_ssl_client_certificate.htm [L,NE,P,E=ssl_authentication_error_detected:1]
  # RewriteRule show typed domain name, proxying to other domain, same query
  #RewriteRule ^ http://terminus.terminus.cz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P,E=ssl_authentication_error_detected:1]
  # RewriteCond {HTTP_REFERER} value is not blank
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
  RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trading\.terminus\.cz$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule show typed domain name, proxying to other domain, same query
  RewriteRule ^ http://terminus.terminus.cz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P,E=ssl_authentication_error_detected:1]
```

When I change proxied url to

```
RewriteRule ^ http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no_ssl_certificate [L,NE,P,E=ssl_authentication_error_detected:1]
```

It starts to changing typed URL in address bar to wordpress permalink, so [P] flag does not work expected way.

And from wordpress virtual host access log

```
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:42 +0200] "GET /index.php/no-ssl-certificate/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17126 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/theme-my-login.css?ver=6.4.5 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-filebase/wp-filebase.css?t=1467256824&ver=3.4.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/plugins/llorix-one-companion//css/style.css?ver=4.5.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/assets/css/style.css?ver=4.5.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.4.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:43 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.3.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/style.css?ver=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.5 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/js/custom.all.js?ver=2.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-content/themes/llorix-one-lite/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
37.48.19.237 - - [19/Jul/2016:09:28:44 +0200] "GET /wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://terminus-dev.terminus.cz/index.php/no-ssl-certificate/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect_canonical filter is responsible for url rewriting. So there is possibility to selectively disable this depending on the requested page.

Solved by placing following code to theme function.php

```
function ssl_certicate_pages_disable_canonical_redirect( $query ) {
   if( 'no_ssl_certificate' == $query->query_vars['pagename'] )
        remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
   if( 'wrong_ssl_certificate' == $query->query_vars['pagename'] )
        remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
 }
 add_action( 'parse_query', 'ssl_certicate_pages_disable_canonical_redirect' );
```